# when upgrading to gradle 8.2 got this error Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, java-17

I recently upgraded my android studio to 2023.1.1 hedgehog as a part of project requirement I upgraded gradle version to 8.1 and AGP to 8.1.1 with jdk 17.0.10 and  following are the version I have choosen for build

```
compileSdkVersion                   = 34 //30  31
buildToolsVersion                   = '34'
targetSdkVersion                    = 34 //31  30
minSdkVersion                       = 21
```

I have tried to downgrade the gradle version to 7.5 with its compatible jdk and agp as answered in previous stackoverflow questions but still getting this error .Previously I was using gradle 6.7.1 here is my gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

and these are my dependencies in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0'
        //classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
        classpath 'com.akaita.android:easylauncher:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:gradle-plugin:0.11.1'
        classpath 'com.ofg:uptodate-gradle-plugin:+'
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.10.1'
//        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
//        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        //classpath 'com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:20.7.1'

    }
}
```

please provide necessary solution to this problem.

Comment: Please provide the full error log